# Use an exception to check if item in dictionary

Tags: c#, hash-map, error-handling

I am using a `KeyNotFoundException` to check if an item exists in a `Dictionary`, creating it when the exception is thrown:

```
public Section GetSection(int plankNo, int sectionNo)
{
    if (plankNo < 1 || plankNo > NumberOfPlanks || sectionNo < 1 || sectionNo > SectionsPerPlank)
    {
        return Section.UNKNOWN;
    }

    try
    {
        return Sections[(plankNo, sectionNo)];
    } catch (KeyNotFoundException)
    {
        var section = new Section(plankNo, sectionNo);
        Sections[(plankNo, sectionNo)] = section;
        return section;
    }
}
```

In Python, this is more or less okay, but in C# it feels "wrong". How can this be made better?

(Note: I mistranslated "shelve" into "plank", but it is everywhere in the system now...)

Comment: Using an exception will cause the stack to unwind every time you find a missing key, which will be very expensive. Just use the `ContainsKey` method on Dictionary, or `TryGetValue`

Comment: Since this is code review and not stack overflow we like to see more of the code to do a good review.

Comment: Your implementation is not thread-safe since the existence check and creation are two separate operations (not a single atomic one as it suppose to). Depending on your application may or may not be a problem but you should be aware of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TryGetValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-6.0) would be the way to go without using `KeyNotFoundException`.
It would look like the below:

```cs
(int, int) key = (plankNo, sectionNo);
if (!Sections.TryGetValue(key, out Section section))
{
    section = new Section(plankNo, sectionNo);
    Sections[key] = section;
}

return section;
```